# Exercise about completion of C[a,b]

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the space $C[a,b]$ with norm $\|f\|_{p}=(\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|^{p}dx )^{p}, 1<p<\infty.$ Fixed $g\in C[a,b], \ g\geq 0,$ define application $T_{g}:C[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$T_{g}(f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx.$$

$a)$ Show that $T_{g} \in (C[a,b])'$ and $\|T_{g}\|=\|g\|_{p'},$ where $p'$ satisfies $\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{p'}=1.$

$b)$ Consider the space $L^{p}(a,b)$ as complement of $C[a,b]$ with norm $\|.\|_{p}.$ Show that exist $T \in (L^{p}(a,b))'$ such that
$$T(f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x), \ \forall f \in C[a,b],$$ with $\|T\|=\|g\|_{p'}.$

For item $a)$, I used Hölder's inequality to show that $\|T_{g}\| \leq \|g\|_{p'}.$ How to show that  $\|T_{g}\| \geq \|g\|_{p'}?$

For item $b)$ I dont have idea.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: For (a). Pick a suitable $f \in C([a,b])$ (depending on $g$) and show $\|T_g(f)\| = \|g\|_{p`}\|f\|_p$. Note that, as $\|T_g\|$ is defined through a supremum, that is enough.

Comment: For (b). What's the hypothesis for $g$? Is $g$ in $C([a,b])$ or $L^{p'}((a,b))$?

Comment: g $\in$ $C[a,b]$.

Comment: Pick $T$ defined through the equation it has to satisfy (that is possible because of (a)), and extend it to $L^p(a,b)$ by density.